# NHibernate Validator with EntityMode.Map

Tags: nhibernate, mapping, entity, validation

I'm developing application with NHibernate EntityMode.Map so I have entities of IDictionary without cs domain model, database configures only with hbm files. It gives me lots of flexibility.

I want to find out does NH.Validator support this EntityMode.Map too? 
If yes how to configure it properly, now I'm getting exceptions related to missing entityType e.g.

```
System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: typeName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just got response in NHibernate forum.

> AFAIK shouldn't work.... well...
>   AFAIK... definitively I can say that
>   NHV, as is, can't work with
>   EntityMode.Map (note "as is", I know
>   the guy have implemented
>   EntityMode.Map and I know a guy
>   working in NHV ;) ).
>
> anyway, if you are interested I'm
>   writing a series of posts about NHV
>   usage.
>   http://fabiomaulo.blogspot.com/2009/10/advanced-nhibernatevalidator.html

from Fabio Maulo